# Minimum system requirements for multiple Azure kinect

Tags: tracking, azurekinect

I note that the minimum requirements for driving one Azure kinect for body tracking is GTX 1070, I want to drive multiple Azure kinects (2~4) on one machine, what is the minimum system requirements then? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

For the SDK, the systems specs are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/system-requirements. Body Tracking only works with a single camera, but multiple instances of the body tracking can be created with each using its own Azure Kinect. A NVIDIA Titan V GPU should be sufficient to run 3-4 instances of body tracking.

One of the hard questions you are asking is how many Kinects can you connect to a single PC. You won't see a spec for this. This is a question of USB Host Controller throughput the performance of the computers backplane, and they are not all the same. I have heard reports of people getting 4 running on a single machine at 30FPS. But that may be multiple USB host controllers. I personally have a machine that can handle 3 devices streaming both depth and color using a single host controller, but they aren't processing or rendering the images.

Answer (score 0):

For recording the video streams (color resolution 1536 and IR NFOV no binning, 30 fps) of three Azure Kinects on one computer a Core i5 10400 with one PCIe NVMe was sufficient. The PC didn't even include a dedicated graphics board.
Are you interested in online body tracking with the k4abt SDK? Or would you like to join the point clouds from the k4a SDK? And do you want to create a real time screen update?
Best, Jens